# Display the contents of a url on a page with out an iframe?

Tags: html, url, iframe

I heard that iframes are going away in newer versions of browsers. I might be wrong. How ever I have an application where you put in the url of a page of content and we will display that content for you.

How would this be achieved with or with out an iframe? what security risks or other issues are presented with an iframe? is there a way to do it with out an iframe? (last I checked this wasn't the 90's)

Comment: Do you have any links stating that iframes will be going away?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iframes are not going away and are handy tools for isolating content withing a page. The Same Origin Policy prevents the Iframe contents from interacting with the parent page.

The other method to display off-site content is to make an AJAX call to a server which acts as a proxy to grab the page content and send it back to the client. In this case, scripts within the AJAX-loaded content can interact with the host page in any way possible.

Comment: Doing it that way, you'd have to correct any relative paths on external resources.

Comment: so your pretty much saying iframe is the way to go? why do they feel so nineties then?

Comment: frame != iframe, that's why.